# What is more efficient in this case, using const char* or std::string

Tags: c++, stdstring, string-literals, storage-duration

I am using a combination of C and C++ code in my application.

I want to print out if a boolean flag is true or false as below, by using a ternary operator to determine the string to print.

If I use a `const char*`, doesn't the compiler more than likely store these string literals `"Yes"` and `"No"` in some read-only memory before the program starts.

If I use `std::string`, when the string goes out of scope, it will be destroyed? But I guess the complier still needs to store the string literals `"Yes"` and `"No"` somewhere anyways? I'm not sure.

```
bool isSet = false;

// More code

//std::string isSetStr = isSet ? "Yes" : "No";
const char* isSetStr  =  isSet ? "Yes" : "No";

//printf ( "Flag is set ? : %s\n", isSetStr.c_str());
printf ( "Flag is set ? : %s\n", isSetStr);
```

Comment: Also consider [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Comment: And yes, the literal strings used to initialized the pointer, the string or the string view will be stored in the executable file and loaded into memory.

Comment: When using `printf` or `std::cout` like you should probably be doing?

Comment: Type of `isSet ? "Yes" : "No"` is `const char*`. it doesn't depends if you store it in `std::string` or `const char*`.

Comment: `std::string` isn't going to work in your C code. It's a non-starter. As it stands this is determined at compile time, so it's inconsequential.

Comment: General rule of thumb: Are you performing this operation *more than a million times*? If not, premature optimization and *doesn't matter*. I doubt you could benchmark the difference here. Focus on getting your code working, then go back and fix any *measurable performance problems* you might have.

Comment: Efficient in terms of what? Memory usage? Runtime overhead? Please define your baseline. Or maybe C++'s stdlib won't fit in your uC's flash? Generaly: FirstRuleOfOptimization - Don't.
SecondRuleOfOptimization - Don't... yet.
ProfileBeforeOptimizing [source](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimization)

Comment: Why use a temporary variable at all? Either use plain `if ... else ...` to print depending on the flag? Or use the ternary conditional expression directly when printing (as in `printf ( "Flag is set ? : %s\n", isSet ? "Yes" : "No" );`)?

Comment: `std::string` is unneeded here.

Comment: The info on the tag "optimization" might offer helpful insights. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optimization/info

Comment: It depends on what else will be done with the string e.g. will it be appended to other strings.   If all you are doing is outputting the string immediately, the difference is insignificant.    You might also want to read up on the subject of "premature optimisation" and also consider using C++ iostreams in C++ rather than C I/O functions like `printf()`.

Answer (score 4):

Either version will allocate the string literals themselves in read-only memory. Either version uses a local variable that goes out of scope, but the string literals remain since they aren't stored locally.

Regarding performance, C++ container classes are almost always going to be more inefficient than "raw" C. When testing your code with g++ -O3 I get this:

```
void test_cstr (bool isSet)
{
  const char* isSetStr  =  isSet ? "Yes" : "No";
  printf ( "Flag is set ? : %s\n", isSetStr);
}
```

Disassembly (x86):

```
.LC0:
        .string "Yes"
.LC1:
        .string "No"
.LC2:
        .string "Flag is set ? : %s\n"
test_cstr(bool):
        test    dil, dil
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        cmove   rsi, rax
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     printf
```

The string literals are loaded into read-only locations and the `isSetStr` variable is simply optimized away.

Now try this using the same compiler and options (-O3):

```
void test_cppstr (bool isSet)
{
  std::string isSetStr = isSet ? "Yes" : "No";
  printf ( "Flag is set ? : %s\n", isSetStr.c_str());
}
```

Disassembly (x86):

```
.LC0:
        .string "Yes"
.LC1:
        .string "No"
.LC2:
        .string "Flag is set ? : %s\n"
test_cppstr(bool):
        push    r12
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        sub     rsp, 32
        test    dil, dil
        cmove   rbx, rax
        lea     rbp, [rsp+16]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rbp
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    strlen
        xor     edx, edx
        mov     esi, eax
        test    eax, eax
        je      .L7
.L6:
        mov     ecx, edx
        add     edx, 1
        movzx   edi, BYTE PTR [rbx+rcx]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp+0+rcx], dil
        cmp     edx, esi
        jb      .L6
.L7:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+16+rax], 0
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        cmp     rdi, rbp
        je      .L1
        call    operator delete(void*)
.L1:
        add     rsp, 32
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
        mov     r12, rax
        jmp     .L4
test_cppstr(bool) [clone .cold]:
.L4:
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        cmp     rdi, rbp
        je      .L5
        call    operator delete(void*)
.L5:
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    _Unwind_Resume
```

The string literals are still allocated in read-only memory so that part is the same. But we got a massive chunk of overhead bloat code.

But on the other hand, the biggest bottleneck by far in this case is the console I/O so the performance of the rest of the code isn't even relevant. Strive to write the most readable code possible and only optimize when you actually need it. Manual string handling in C is fast, but it's also very error-prone and cumbersome.

Comment: Notably, Bjarne Stroustrup has been telling us since the early 80s that std::string is equally fast as character arrays and the problem was always with bad compilers and not with the C++ language. So we mustn't disassemble code like this with the latest gcc from 2021 and learn the actual truth. Surely Bjarne was always correct, std::string is perfect and all C++ compilers ever made are broken, right?

Comment: I guess sometimes he is a salesman more than a language-lawyer ;)

Comment: One problem with `std::string` is that the class is so hideously bloated (probably the best example I can think of as how *not* to write a class in C++) that it's very hard for a C++ compiler to tackle effectively. Perhaps a good C++ compiler is therefore yet to emerge?

Comment: Saying that `std::string` is bloated is wrong, IMHO. It's way too small for any serious string manipulation and the very *few* method it implements are actually redundant and useless. I think they have placed the cursor at the wrong place here between a C char array and a real useful string class. It's too close to a C array with all the additional overhead of allocation/deallocation. You have to write all the string manipulation yourself, so it's very bug prone.

Answer (score 3):

You can test it with [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/v1jaEz8PY).
The former (using `const char*`) gives this:

```
.LC0:
        .string "No"
.LC1:
        .string "Yes"
.LC2:
        .string "Flag is set ? : %s\n"
a(bool):
        test    dil, dil
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        cmove   rsi, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     printf
```

The latter (using std::string) gives this:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Yes"
.LC1:
        .string "No"
.LC2:
        .string "Flag is set ? : %s\n"
a(bool):
        push    r12
        push    rbp
        mov     r12d, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        push    rbx
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        sub     rsp, 32
        test    dil, dil
        lea     rax, [rsp+16]
        cmovne  r12, rsi
        or      rcx, -1
        mov     rdi, r12
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
        xor     eax, eax
        repnz scasb
        not     rcx
        lea     rbx, [rcx-1]
        mov     rbp, rcx
        cmp     rbx, 15
        jbe     .L3
        mov     rdi, rcx
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+16], rbx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
.L3:
        cmp     rbx, 1
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        jne     .L4
        mov     dl, BYTE PTR [r12]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax], dl
        jmp     .L5
.L4:
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .L5
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rsi, r12
        mov     rcx, rbx
        rep movsb
.L5:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rbx
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax-1+rbp], 0
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        lea     rax, [rsp+16]
        cmp     rdi, rax
        je      .L6
        call    operator delete(void*)
        jmp     .L6
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        lea     rdx, [rsp+16]
        mov     rbx, rax
        cmp     rdi, rdx
        je      .L8
        call    operator delete(void*)
.L8:
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume
.L6:
        add     rsp, 32
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
```

Using `std::string_view` such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string_view>


int a(bool isSet) {

// More code

std::string_view isSetStr = isSet ? "Yes" : "No";
//const char* isSetStr  =  isSet ? "Yes" : "No";

printf ( "Flag is set ? : %s\n", isSetStr.data());
//printf ( "Flag is set ? : %s\n", isSetStr);
}
```

gives:

```
.LC0:
        .string "No"
.LC1:
        .string "Yes"
.LC2:
        .string "Flag is set ? : %s\n"
a(bool):
        test    dil, dil
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        cmove   rsi, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     printf
```

So to sum up, both `const char*` and `string_view` gives optimal code. `string_view` is a bit more code to type compared to `const char*`.
`std::string` is made to manipulate string content, so it's overkill here and leads to less efficient code.

Another remark with `string_view`: It does not guarantee that the string is NUL terminated. In this case, it is, since it's built from a NUL terminated static string. For a generic `string_view` usage with `printf`, use `printf("%.*s", str.length(), str.data());`

EDIT: By disabling exception handling, you can reduce `std::string` version to:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Yes"
.LC1:
        .string "No"
.LC2:
        .string "Flag is set ? : %s\n"
a(bool):
        push    r12
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        push    rbp
        mov     ebp, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 32
        test    dil, dil
        cmove   rbp, rax
        lea     r12, [rsp+16]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], r12
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    strlen
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     rdi, r12
        lea     rdx, [rbp+0+rax]
        mov     rbx, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy_chars(char*, char const*, char const*)
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rbx
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax+rbx], 0
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose()
        add     rsp, 32
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
```

which is still a lot more than the `string_view`'s version. Remark that the compiler was smart enough to remove the memory allocation on the heap here, but it's still forced to compute the string's length (even if printf will also compute it itself).

Comment: for bringing in string_view +1, but note: In your examples the ternary operator is optimized away.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the post for removing the optimization.

Comment: you should show the code that produces the output. And did you turn on optimizations? With `std::string` I get this https://godbolt.org/z/sev6od9c7 (a little less than yours)

Comment: I've added the link to the godbolt used. I've used `-Os` where you've used `-O3`. But the difference is subtle and does not change the conclusion that `std::string` is generating larger code.

Answer (score 3):

Chill out!

The `printf` will be **orders of magnitude slower** than any construction of a `std::string` from `const char[]` data embedded in the program source code.

*Always* use a profiler when examining code performance. Writing a small program in an attempt to test a hypothesis will often fail to tell you anything about what is happening in your big program. In the case you present, a good compiler will optimise to

```
int main(){printf ( "Flag is set ? : No\n");}
```

Comment: Almost all compiler will replace this call to `puts` so it'll be as fast as it can be. You are right that printf here is the bottleneck through.

Comment: I agree with the first part and the general message - but you seem to have tried to optimise "//more code" and assumed that isSet is const.

Comment: @UKMonkey: I'm being facetious and am taking `// more code literally`. What I'm really trying to get across is that you need to use a profiler on your real program to measure performance. Although I have reworded the answer a little.

Answer (score 1):

String literals have static storage duration, They are alive until program ends.

Pay attention to that if you are using in a program the same string literal it is not necessary that the compiler stores this string literal as one object.

That is this expression

```
"Yes" == "Yes"
```

can yield either true or false depending on compiler options. But usually by defaults identical string literals are stored as one string literal.

Objects of the type `std::string` if they are not declared in a namespace and without the keyword `static` has automatic storage duration. It means that when the control is passed to a block such an object is created anew and destroyed each time when the control leaves the block.

Comment: All subject to the *as-if* rule, of course. But I know you're aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Type of `isSet ? "Yes" : "No"` is `const char*`, independently of the fact that you store it inside `std::string` or a `const char*` (or `std::stringview`, or ...). (so string literals are treated equally by the compiler).

According to [quick-bench.com](https://quick-bench.com/q/JjExX60MEI7ACsbi_DipGhNk8oU),

`std::string` version is ~6 times slower, which is understandable as it requires extra dynamic allocation.

Unless you need the extra feature of `std::string`, you might stay with `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent C++ code:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_literals;

void test_cppstr (bool isSet)
{
  const std::string& isSetStr = isSet ? "Yes"s : "No"s;
  printf ( "Flag is set ? : %s\n", isSetStr.c_str());
}
```

Efficient almost like C version.

Edit: This version has small overhead with setup/exit, but has same efficiency as C code in calling `printf`.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_literals;

const std::string yes("Yes");
const std::string no("No");

void test_cppstr (bool isSet)
{
  const std::string& isSetStr = isSet ? yes : no;
  printf ( "Flag is set ? : %s\n", isSetStr.c_str());
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/v3ebcsrYE

Comment: It is less efficient than C of course, but more efficient than original version with dynamic memory allocation. And this is because C code is not equivalent with C++ code. This version is more closely resembles C version.

Comment: @Jarod42 This depends from `std::string` implementation. Some implementations allow keeping string without dynamic allocations. See for example link above.

Comment: If SSO can apply to your version, it can also apply to OP version.